# Scaling websites on KDE

Tags: 19.10, plasma, kde5

I'm a junior webdev, I've recently switched to Linux.

Currently, I'm using Kubuntu 19.10 with 5.18.3 KDE Plasma. I'm using Chrome as the web browser. My global scaling is set to 100%.

All pages appear zoomed out by default, compared to what is seen on Windows. Since the vast majority of users uses Windows with default settings, I'd like to view websites exactly the way they do. Is there a way to match the zoom level exactly?

I've been messing with both global scaling and chrome's default zoom level a bit, nevertheless no combination of these settings seemed to give the desired zoom level.

Comment: Is it possible to include images to show the difference?